# Embedded C# in C++ using mono cannot find System.dll

Tags: c#, c++, scripting, mono, interop

I'm trying to embed C# scripts into my C++ Game Engine Project, so I followed this example which uses mono: [gist-link](https://gist.github.com/zwcloud/b342d264176ee2143aca970a9933e5cc). The code itself runs fine, I can access the methods of the class, but I have a throw whenever I try to call the Console.WriteLine() function. It seems I can't use System functions inside my scripts.

Here is the log for the throw for the function:

Dog.cs:

```
public class Dog
{
    static public void Type()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a Dog!");
    }

    ...
}
```

Error log:

```
Running the static method: Dog:Type()

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Console' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ConsoleDriver' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sys' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.LChflagsCanSetHiddenFlag()
  at Interop+Sys..cctor () [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.Exists (System.String path) [0x0001e] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.TermInfoDriver.SearchTerminfo (System.String term) [0x00044] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.TermInfoDriver..ctor (System.String term) [0x0004b] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.ConsoleDriver.CreateTermInfoDriver (System.String term) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.ConsoleDriver..cctor () [0x0004d] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Console.SetupStreams (System.Text.Encoding inputEncoding, System.Text.Encoding outputEncoding) [0x00007] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.Console..cctor () [0x0007d] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Dog.Type () [0x00000] in <f155b242589444d6a2f6baf230b1c326>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Console' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ConsoleDriver' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sys' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.LChflagsCanSetHiddenFlag()
  at Interop+Sys..cctor () [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.Exists (System.String path) [0x0001e] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.TermInfoDriver.SearchTerminfo (System.String term) [0x00044] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.TermInfoDriver..ctor (System.String term) [0x0004b] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.ConsoleDriver.CreateTermInfoDriver (System.String term) [0x00000] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.ConsoleDriver..cctor () [0x0004d] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Console.SetupStreams (System.Text.Encoding inputEncoding, System.Text.Encoding outputEncoding) [0x00007] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
  at System.Console..cctor () [0x0007d] in <de882a77e7c14f8ba5d298093dde82b2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Dog.Type () [0x00000] in <f155b242589444d6a2f6baf230b1c326>:0
```

In this throw I get that System.DllNotFoundException was called, but I have called

```
    mono_set_dirs("/usr/lib/", "/etc/");
```

to set mono to find the dlls at /usr/lib/mono/4.5/.
The dll is there so I don't understand.

I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I have mono installed locally and linked to my project using the .so file.

I have tried moving the System.dll from /usr/lib/mono/4.5/ to my repository and link it manually, but that didn't change anything.

To call manually I did:

```
mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "System.dll");
```

Comment: Have you read through this github thread? : https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21061

Comment: I didn't found this thread, thank you very much, I read online that it could have been an issue about the env, but unsetting it manually before running my code didn't solve the issue. For some reason, unsetting it inside my cpp program fixed it!